# Magento module Development

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Can any Magento experts point me out to some good resources to Magento Module Development  . I already tried to Magento Doc not very helpfull especially from development point of view. 
Like Magento offer a lot of Built in Features to get different information.

```
<?php $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();?>
<?php $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();?>
```

Specially more of these kinds ......

Any place where I can find list of all these or atleast most frequently used once to speed up the learning and understanding process.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: There is no one place to learn Magento in full.  You just have to search around for tutorials and articles and build up your knowledge.  If you're looking for an easy pass, there is none.  It takes practice, focus, hard work and time to master Magento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does take hard work and you have to start somewhere.  This is the best place to start:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-1-introduction-to-magento

Go through parts 1-8.

Then this is really good: http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/Magento-Extension-Developers-Guide-v1.0.pdf

Then start going thru tutorials that you can find on the internet.  It takes quite a bit of work, but it is learnable.

Answer (score 0):

This has been a great for a couple of my employees in helping  understanding the folder structure and naming conventions.  I am a hands on learner myself, I wish this was around when I started years ago.

Check this out.  Its a module creator.  Create it using names you can follow and you can follow the path and structure quite easily.

http://www.mgt-commerce.com/kickstarter/